# react-native - get text inside all <b> tags in a html string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Let's say i have a html string in `react native`. Since theres no `document` in `react-native`, im a bit confused on how this can be achieved

```
const htmlString = '<div style="margin-left: 10px">I have three dogs. One is called <b>Tiger</b>, the second is called <b>Lion</b>, and the third is called <b>Panda</b>.</div>'
```

I want to extract the text inside each `<b>` tag. There can be more than 10 `<b>` tags in this html string. The `<b>` tag can also be nested on many levels within the string

Expected output:

```
Tiger
Lion
Panda
```

This data can be stored in array or as object.
Please note: This is in `react-native`

Thank you

I tried something like

```
htmlString.split('<b>').pop().split('</b>')[0]
```

that returns only `Panda`. cannot find a way to get the previous ones too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
const reg = /<b>(.*?)<\/b>/g
for (const match of htmlString.matchAll(reg)) {
  console.log(`matched: ${match[1]}`);
}
```

Result:

```
matched: Tiger
matched: Lion
matched: Panda
```

Comment: exactly what i was expecting. thank you very much